# Type hint the "with" value of a context manager

Tags: python, python-typing

I am looking to create some interfaces for extending a concise SQL library to use different SQL databases using a plugin/bridge pattern. I modeled this on sqlite3 since that is packaged with Python, and I used a context manager that connects to the sqlite3 database file on `__init__` and returns the cursor on `__enter__`. I have abstracted this such that the base query builder takes a context manager that returns a cursor (via runtime checkable protocol) as an argument:

```py
@runtime_checkable
class CursorProtocol(Protocol):
    def execute(sql: str) -> CursorProtocol:
        ...

    def fetchone() -> Any:
        ...


@runtime_checkable
class ContextManagerProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, *args) -> None:
        ...

    def __enter__(self) -> CursorProtocol:
        ...

    def __exit__(self, __exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
                __exc_value: Optional[BaseException],
                __traceback: Optional[TracebackType]) -> None:
        ...


class SqliteContext:
    """Context manager for sqlite."""
    connection: sqlite3.Connection
    cursor: sqlite3.Cursor

    def __init__(self, model: type) -> None:
        assert type(model) is type, 'model must be child class of SqliteModel'
        assert issubclass(model, SqliteModel), \
            'model must be child class of SqliteModel'
        assert type(model.file_path) in (str, bytes), \
            'model.file_path must be str or bytes'
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(model.file_path)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def __enter__(self) -> CursorProtocol:
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, __exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
                __exc_value: Optional[BaseException],
                __traceback: Optional[TracebackType]) -> None:
        if __exc_type is not None:
            self.connection.rollback()
        else:
            self.connection.commit()

        self.connection.close()


@dataclass
class SqlQueryBuilder:
    model: type
    context_manager: ContextManagerProtocol = field(default=None)
    // a lot more code
    def count(self) -> int:
        """Returns the number of records matching the query."""
        sql = f'select count(*) from {self.model.table}'

        if len(self.clauses) > 0:
            sql += ' where ' + ' and '.join(self.clauses)

        with self.context_manager(self.model) as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql, self.params)
            return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

The updated code passes the extensive unit test suite I modified for the abstraction process. However, the code editor does not properly pick up on the `def __enter__(self) -> CursorProtocol:` type hint. If I use `with SqliteContext(self.model) as cursor` instead of `with self.context_manager(self.model) as cursor`, the `CursorProtocol` type hint works as expected; i.e. `cursor.{method}` calls are properly annotated.

Is this a bug with my code editor, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `context_manager: ContextManagerProtocol` line. The solution was to change it to `context_manager: Type[ContextManagerProtocol]`:

```py
@dataclass
class SqlQueryBuilder:
    model: type
    context_manager: Type[ContextManagerProtocol] = field(default=None)
    ...
```